# Installed pygraphviz on Windows 7, but unable to import it; can't find _graphviz

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am trying to install pygraphviz on my 64-bit installation of Windows 7 SP1. I was able to get the usual `python setup.py install` command to work by correcting the following lines of the `setup.py` file:

```
include_dirs = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\include"
library_dirs = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\lib\release\lib"
```

When I try to import it, though, I get the following error:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygraphviz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pygraphviz\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from .agraph import AGraph, Node, Edge, Attribute, ItemAttribute
  File "pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import graphviz as gv
  File "pygraphviz\graphviz.py", line 28, in <module>
    _graphviz = swig_import_helper()
  File "pygraphviz\graphviz.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _graphviz
ImportError: No module named _graphviz
```

This is puzzling because the directory pygraphviz gets installed to does contain a `_graphviz.pyd` file. If I go to that directory and try to import it, I get a different ImportError:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pygraphviz>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import _graphviz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

So as far as I can tell, the _graphviz.pyd file seems to have been improperly compiled (I am using mingw32, having edited my distutils.cfg file accordingly). I can't find any other instances of this problem from other pygraphviz users. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I did for a perfectly working install. Running Python 2.7.8 using the Anaconda distribution on Windows 64-bit SP1 as well.

1. Download and install `Graphviz 2.38` from [here](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php).
2. Download the binary installer for `pygraphviz` from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygraphviz). Use the appropriate version (`pygraphviz‑1.2.win‑amd64‑py2.7.exe`). Install. Make sure the installer detects your correct `PYTHONPATH`.

Result:

[image]

Comment: I also encountered the _graphviz import problem. After I add `C:\Program Files\Graphviz\bin` to PATH environment varible the error is gone.